# C++/Mac Screenshot in OpenCV

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I need OpenCV to get data from the screen of my Mac.  This is what I have tried; it gets a CGImageRef:

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    CGImageRef an_image = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID());
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to convert `an_image` to an OpenCV `Mat`?  I have found a way to convert from a `UIImage` (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html) but it looks like I can't use UIImages in C++ (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171631).  I could try to use Objective-C for part of my code, but I would prefer not to since I haven't used that language before.

Alternatively, is there a way to take a screenshot in a different format (not CGImageRef)?

Comment: Looking at that tutorial code, it uses the `CGImage` member of `UIImage` for most of the work, so that's basically what you're looking for...

Comment: You could use `system()` and call `/usr/sbin/screencapture /tmp/image.ppm` and then easily parse the file `/tmp/image.ppm` since it's a very simple NetPBM file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format

Comment: You probably have `ffmpeg` installed anyway for OpenCV, so you could use `popen()` with `ffmpeg` to grab the screen and read it from a pipe without the intermediate file necessary with `screencapture` I suggested above.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments!  I took a closer look at the tutorial; I modified the code so that it works without UIImage.  I'll take a look at NetPBM and ffmpeg as well.